# Ruby On Rails convert JSON to firebase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, firebase, rubygems

I would like save api results directly to firebase.
I am use firebase-ruby gem and sample push query from docs looks that way `firebase.push("todos", { :name => 'Pick the milk', :'.priority' => 1 })`

Is there a gem or converter to convert my api result:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```

to:

```
"result", {
  :userId => 1,
  :id => 1,
  :title => 'delectus aut autem',
  :completed => false
}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{}.to_json
```

is the first step. the "result", could be done with a concatenation with the string and the result from ".to_json"